# Anchor tag doesn't work inside of svg foreignObject

Tags: html, css, svg, recharts, foreignobject

Anchor tag doesn't work (css hover works, but once clicked don't lead anywhere) inside of svg foreignObject. I have the following markup for a custom Recharts (graph library) Label

```
<foreignObject>
    <div className="annotation-tooltip">
        <a href="https://some-link" target="_blank">
            some text
        </a>
    </div>
</foreignObject>
```

When I click on a tag nothing happens. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: please add a width and a height to the foreignObject

Comment: Yes, there's a set  width and height I've just  simplified the example. So the  main thing is that a tag doesn't lead anywhere  once clicked. When it's on a Recharts chart.